# Adapters from Australia to Canada

Tags: voltage, frequency, adapter

I am in Australia and going to Canada

I have 2 laptops that I want to take with me. and other electical stuff such as shaving machine and electrical teethbrush.

I am going to get Canadian plus with me like this one

[image]

but I read in this website that voltage and frequency are different

https://www.power-plugs-sockets.com/au/canada/

I dont know what does that mean and will my elecrical stuff are going to work or i am going to damage them?!!

I took a photo of my 2 laptops adapters.

[image]

[image]

can I use my laptops in canada?

will that cause any damage to other electrical stuff?

Comment: Questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic as this site is intended specifically for questions on electronics design.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, both are designed for so-called "universal mains"
Check both labels:
**INPUT: 100-240V~ 50-60Hz**

So, it is suitable for 230 V~ 50 Hz (Australia) as well as for 120 V~ 60 Hz (Canada) as both fall within above specified range.